# most pythonic way to retrieve first element from a list in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume I have a list called my_list and it can be an empty list and I am using python 3.6+

which is the most pythonic way to get first element from a list?

```
next(iter(my_list))
mylist[0] if my_list else None
first, *_ = my_list
```

or if there is other way please specify.
If all methods are good in a certain scenario please describe the best scenario for each of the way

Comment: `first, *_ = []` (note order of characters) will fail too

Comment: The most Pythonic way depends on what you want to do with this. For example, two raise a noticeable error, the other suppresses it with a default value. Do you *expect* the list to be empty?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the goal is to determine most pythonic way to get first item of a list that may be empty....Using index method does not look like most pythonic

Comment: If it is likely that the list is empty, the index method is by far the fastest -- thereby being the most practical. Which is a major part of being Pythonic. But all of that depends on what you want to do *with* this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi can you please describe in an answer with example cases where one is prefered for another.

Comment: @IamMashed No, I can't. Your question doesn't make it clear what an appropriate, objective answer is.

Comment: Instead of focusing on "*what's the most pythonic*" (which is, as pointed out, a bit vague/unclear), focus instead on the use-case. Do you want speed/performance? Do you want something that will fail fast or raise an exception? Is the list ever going to be empty? Are you sure that it's always a list, and not a generator? For example, a "pythonic" one-liner can be bad for performance or would not handle most error cases. Focus on the use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `mylist[0] if my_list else None` would be a good way to go.

Comment: they all seem to be good ways....which one is the most pythonic?

Comment: Nope they are not `first, *_ = my_list` will fail if list is empty.

Comment: `next(iter(my_list))` will raise an `StopIteration`  error if the list is empty

Comment: You picked the one that only works for sequences. At least, the other two are more general as they can be applied to any iterable.

Comment: @schwobaseggl OP has mentioned `list` in the question heading,

Comment: True, but since this is clearly opinion based, this would be at least an argument.